# Building Rust application with static linking fails

Tags: docker, gcc, rust, docker-compose

I was told in another question that it would be beneficial to compile my app with static linking.

My current build looks like this:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=-crt-static' cross build --release --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

When I change the -crt-static to a +crt-static I get a big error message from cc. It says:

```
 = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcpUOomm/symbols.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.podfetch.21a8047f-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0.4g79pr45y1fnejb0.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps" "-L" "/target/release/deps" "-L" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/ring-530d14df55c88f58/out" "-L" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/zstd-sys-0bc533e3b6fd5029/out" "-L" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/libsqlite3-sys-b15bd386ddab9e91/out" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libjsonwebtoken-7069d5e1e448bf14.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libpem-793ad67692e64416.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsimple_asn1-909bff66618d5dd9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libnum_bigint-755061fde1c9f533.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librpassword-190d34ea07db4e3b.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librtoolbox-310b049ac4690b6d.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libawc-d4e3df15fbd6fcbb.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfrankenstein-cfe4d0de0cadd5e7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libureq-7bb6df8ee492d010.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbase64-a1da583077385afc.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmultipart-7bcd67d766a2c9ac.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtempfile-e8a4615421a89a4a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfastrand-8f973fc4c733a132.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libenv_logger-0a38b3084365f293.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtermcolor-81124e21fbaf3383.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libis_terminal-4d560a8a4d24d3da.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librustix-fe54ce91885ca474.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblinux_raw_sys-d4cd1b74206a6929.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libio_lifetimes-68fddcb0145ed105.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhumantime-769e71c844e44034.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libdotenv-10e0b9b53336f519.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libuuid-99330b4704c4085b.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_web_actors-b9fe23212f1298e1.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsha256-18171f0c805b5980.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhex-f36724539f0ee049.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsysinfo-b9ea7ae92c0e0dfc.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librayon-3f3531b16eb852d6.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librayon_core-034d5aa5598500a4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcrossbeam_deque-89cbe951a1185e09.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcrossbeam_epoch-ea8fe7697e05a4b1.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmemoffset-6fb15fdbe5d8163d.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libeither-592f0ecb002fb05f.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfs_extra-564b523d51eb7d0f.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libxml_builder-9e892aab8afb355d.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtokio_stream-6b8023e5dcd0c46a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librss-6ae46b36d7344b57.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libnever-a0a6da9c1429968d.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libquick_xml-eceeb41650ead95c.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libderive_builder-9c3828c86697932f.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libreqwest-8118bc2abfa91af2.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhyper_tls-bbaa3370956a30c3.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libipnet-4794f0a3a5a5261a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtokio_native_tls-b856e890b1baa1a4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libnative_tls-4f4b6a1a8007924a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libopenssl_probe-2b7afdd2b3b755b6.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libopenssl-8d1e77d75a11de63.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libforeign_types-d2677185a76e1b84.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libforeign_types_shared-6cc4c966f4cdec86.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libopenssl_sys-047f2db6b3d9eb90.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhyper-9fe855c0289e0ad7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libwant-378f1c286f054eeb.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtry_lock-e3bb0d8c06030ef7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtower_service-fb51295d139af0f2.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhttp_body-64c37959bd03ff80.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libopml-12adada4809992b3.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libthiserror-15514bc5b1a40843.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhard_xml-116080e9d2c1c4fe.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblazy_static-08437635546db985.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libjetscii-fc4e255765483108.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libxmlparser-db938cbf8fbd5df4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures-db10ccc68f67eccc.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures_executor-26326d9daa1064d9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libutoipa_swagger_ui-1a58fb3f74eeb478.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librust_embed-9c30f88f907df5d9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librust_embed_utils-19a17d032d6f76c2.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libwalkdir-1b1a9f7f995f67a7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsame_file-22de0bdeb1a980af.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsha2-3ae40a389295001f.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libutoipa-5a1e9632f67ede03.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libclokwerk-795d581c2d82ef6c.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_files-6b20e4e797768f1a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhttp_range-07966ffab0e976fe.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libaskama_escape-3644b5f0a948e26d.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmime_guess-db8702439e50a9c6.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libunicase-a5a727173c63c07c.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_web-1623491cbd10c877.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcookie-3451722a305181ea.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtime-32c904d943849d82.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtime_core-1e8bc58d11b2f965.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libahash-81270d2e07da4799.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liburl-805a3925dfddbd34.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libidna-3572e2e37325755c.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libunicode_normalization-07dc6b45f930f0af.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtinyvec-33d4a833e9aa1623.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtinyvec_macros-8998e2ec9bd6a919.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libunicode_bidi-fd3a5c882939a701.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libserde_urlencoded-4dab5ea45fbe1e04.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libform_urlencoded-2ef77de7d095f8f9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_server-012e93536c7f3f32.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_router-18d7d76d8e08a6e4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libregex-8b2a7178c5b93b31.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libaho_corasick-5904dfc5d2276786.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libregex_syntax-29082b3187eb81fe.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_http-1a232559c07b9aee.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librand-15b6a3de9b98a77a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librand_chacha-67e106d96a37e0bc.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libppv_lite86-71b0d3826ae2cbe0.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librand_core-7ec2af694a0ce3b7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhttparse-8c581cad26c9fb61.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbrotli-fe8ec0ca14c8ccdb.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbrotli_decompressor-dedc87cfd50d03ff.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liballoc_stdlib-52ecd5a595288f5a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liballoc_no_stdlib-587e8eea6d536449.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhttpdate-f520da14968aefad.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsha1-1febb95aa8f98a02.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcpufeatures-fa8055210d6a6f74.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libdigest-4689aa3b2feb9f12.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libblock_buffer-8917aaed9fb2e8b3.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcrypto_common-f167fa54ce642da4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libgeneric_array-59badbdbff28910d.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtypenum-0abd1be38dc9ba1e.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbase64-ad8e1cff50e9e149.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblocal_channel-9ff7b6980e47c810.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbytestring-c620822098c6fd08.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libencoding_rs-a89c083b1fc1010e.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblanguage_tags-71529b7c7370ae72.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libahash-a09049fdbc77caa9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libgetrandom-e1bc9d5b56381d61.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmime-c0ad824565ba90ce.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libpercent_encoding-aa995b9eaec021a4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libh2-6a3b2eaf834fa721.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libindexmap-2ef06ef854241dd7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhashbrown-c68fa5cf0d2b024e.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_tls-d0b0fd0d2a4a40f7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libwebpki_roots-61667481260953dc.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtokio_rustls-c38b577d4b150690.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/librustls-e7ec703cccf2b00e.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsct-624b76640b797471.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libwebpki-eb78021db57fa350.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libring-a737688fc42382b6.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libspin-1a40be090da818ce.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libuntrusted-53e3b9217f3c422e.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libzstd-db84e4a287f9f054.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libzstd_safe-6e1bd68e69404779.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libzstd_sys-8fbbd22704505857.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libflate2-4484a3e66ef5fe29.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libminiz_oxide-1b5d902b526eb9da.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libadler-3cc20b865dbaa656.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcrc32fast-6de1787c36e36cfd.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_codec-6cd4ba2363c8cf29.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_utils-9438dddb373ed264.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblocal_waker-08f13d4be8a78e15.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libhttp-662db6a3f80f8115.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfnv-c3f3b38cebc752b4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_service-fbafd18f1562585b.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix-d142b1eb75524662.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcrossbeam_channel-8a1653dde03f04c9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcrossbeam_utils-ac13f58d20bae8b0.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtokio_util-0ee9da662a8c7439.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtracing-cc1f9047f0cd5f65.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtracing_core-ca5032f765f514e9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libonce_cell-acc091b9fdfb676c.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures_util-865ee730c0477e7b.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmemchr-5ecdfde0318e8ad9.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures_io-c2aac215c46de127.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libslab-1457ac3b64602eec.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures_channel-ff21ef8fcaca4099.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures_sink-e233299eb9f30380.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures_task-b4f67ac546dc55be.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libpin_utils-a9645b16db92c7ef.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbitflags-3ddcd7099cf0df2f.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libactix_rt-55f6d6633a28f2c7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtokio-81dec80a78d037a7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsignal_hook_registry-bc967aff672eef13.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libnum_cpus-4dd610d445bee3a1.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsocket2-96263791a33ff935.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libbytes-2200c50af24317de.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmio-fd7e940e9cb20a39.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libpin_project_lite-34892c1bfbe4fd53.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libfutures_core-d2088d222235d1ee.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libdiesel_migrations-1b673544164bce66.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libmigrations_internals-70ef7fbc7d0112c7.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtoml-d2904eb80d18e918.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libdiesel-808e309daa851b97.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libr2d2-71ca2fc1ae4ced81.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libscheduled_thread_pool-b7561109e33502fb.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libparking_lot-b18e9f866021eb0c.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libparking_lot_core-7a330f5b89dc3163.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblibc-c7c14962062c97df.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsmallvec-28135caf116c8bb5.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblock_api-174564713b574182.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libscopeguard-9181de7e62cd035a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblog-cd93acf0e40c6d85.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libcfg_if-d695d25c733513a4.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libchrono-7239b3d5f3e5678b.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libiana_time_zone-91fe0c8d72f8194a.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libnum_integer-868dd946066fd7a5.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libnum_traits-01ddc455ef065554.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblibsqlite3_sys-ddc406bb36c1de6d.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libserde_json-38f5dfa12b4c1367.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libryu-6a991d2257de5a2b.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libitoa-1a023132a337c1b5.rlib" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libserde-442bf8759a674b5e.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-89bc084783fdc439.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-8bee4b287d4367c1.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-d61707aed80694c0.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-d85366256f22345b.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-96069b86b8a8cae9.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-d19d53abf68dfa6c.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-787cbccd19d64ac6.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-b3837a36b830e0d0.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-e3deb0e7e3f04966.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-dabbb79c9815def4.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-305b01f34c9409f2.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-f833521df6074e73.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-9ac333113350d171.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-1c126114322d0eee.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-bad9164fdeeecf92.rlib" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-lgcc_eh" "-lgcc" "-lc" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-f9374b1e480fa681.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-207f06e41d9603af.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-7e2768e66e984e85.rlib" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-957b4aff41f8cd46.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lssl" "-lcrypto" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/podfetch-3c46653104b3c7b0" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-static-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/liblibsqlite3_sys-ddc406bb36c1de6d.rlib(sqlite3.o): in function `unixDlOpen':
          sqlite3.c:(.text.unixDlOpen+0xd): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
          /usr/bin/ld: /target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsysinfo-b9ea7ae92c0e0dfc.rlib(sysinfo-b9ea7ae92c0e0dfc.sysinfo.429c13b0-cgu.6.rcgu.o): in function `core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnMut<A> for &mut F>::call_mut':
          sysinfo.429c13b0-cgu.6:(.text._ZN4core3ops8function5impls79_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnMut$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$mut$u20$F$GT$8call_mut17h71401f289a62691aE+0x26d): warning: Using 'getgrouplist' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
          /usr/bin/ld: /target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libsysinfo-b9ea7ae92c0e0dfc.rlib(sysinfo-b9ea7ae92c0e0dfc.sysinfo.429c13b0-cgu.6.rcgu.o): in function `core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnMut<A> for &mut F>::call_mut':
          sysinfo.429c13b0-cgu.6:(.text._ZN4core3ops8function5impls79_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnMut$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$mut$u20$F$GT$8call_mut17h5c2a278c81835b46E+0x13): warning: Using 'getgrgid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
          /usr/bin/ld: /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-89bc084783fdc439.rlib(std-89bc084783fdc439.std.5f6d52e5-cgu.0.rcgu.o): in function `std::sys::unix::os::home_dir::fallback':
          /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/std/src/sys/unix/os.rs:638: warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
          /usr/bin/ld: /root/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-89bc084783fdc439.rlib(std-89bc084783fdc439.std.5f6d52e5-cgu.0.rcgu.o): in function `<std::sys_common::net::LookupHost as core::convert::TryFrom<(&str,u16)>>::try_from::{{closure}}':
          /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library/std/src/sys_common/net.rs:207: warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
          /usr/bin/ld: /target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libjsonwebtoken-7069d5e1e448bf14.rlib(jsonwebtoken-7069d5e1e448bf14.jsonwebtoken.67223599-cgu.5.rcgu.o): undefined reference to symbol '__tls_get_addr@@GLIBC_2.3'
          /usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)
```

I am building with the ghcr.io/cross-rs/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu cross docker images and installing extra dependencies with:

```
RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64 && apt update && apt install gcc libssl-dev:arm64   \
    linux-libc-dev git -y
```

My current dependencies look like this:

```
[package]
name = "podfetch"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
build = "build.rs"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[build-dependencies]
built = {version="0.6.0", features=["git2", "chrono", "semver"]}

[dependencies]
awc =  {version="3.1.1", features = ["rustls"]}
rpassword = "7.2.0"
reqwest = {version="0.11.14", features = ["blocking", "json", "async-compression", "rustls", "stream"]}
tokio-stream = { version = "0.1.14", features = ["sync"] }
actix = "0.13.0"
async-recursion = "1.0.2"
base64 = "0.21.0"
uuid = {version="1.3.1", features = ["v4", "serde"]}
libsqlite3-sys = {version = "0.26.0", features = ["bundled"]}
diesel_migrations = "2.0.0"
actix-files = "0.6.2"
actix-web = {version="4.3.0", features=["rustls"]}
jsonwebtoken = {version="8.2.0"}
log = "0.4.17"
futures-util = "0.3.28"
opml = "1.1.5"
rand = "0.8.5"
env_logger = "0.10.0"
chrono = {version  = "0.4.23", default-features=false, features = ["serde"]}
actix-web-actors = "4.2.0"
rss = "2.0.2"
frankenstein = "0.25.0"
regex = "1.8.1"
xml-builder = "0.5.2"
diesel = { version = "2.0.4", features = ["sqlite", "returning_clauses_for_sqlite_3_35", "chrono", "r2d2"] }
r2d2 = "0.8.10"
utoipa = { version = "3", features = ["actix_extras"] }
futures = "0.3.28"
utoipa-swagger-ui = {version = "3", features = ["actix-web"] }
clokwerk= "0.4.0"
tokio = {version = "1.24.2", features = ["full"]}
serde = "1.0.162"
serde_derive = "1.0.152"
sysinfo = {version = "0.29.0", features = ["serde"]}
fs_extra = "1.3.0"
serde_json = "1.0.93"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
sha1 = "0.10.5"
sha256 = "1.1.3"
```

with the source code of the app being [here](https://github.com/SamTV12345/PodFetch/tree/armv7/sup)

Please note: A minimal example doesn't make sense in this context as the solution will be specific to my app.

Comment: Of course a minimal example makes sense. You need to minimize your code more and more until you find the minimal code that triggers the same error.

Comment: I don't think that this can be objectively discussed.

Comment: did you find a solution, I am facing the similiar issue when build musl static link lib.

Comment: Yes I got in contact with the cross maintainers. Musl doesn't really work. Blackdex Rust Musl images work perfectly. https://github.com/BlackDex/rust-musl